# Mql4 order is not close auto

Tags: mql4

I want to back test simple EA only BUY with MT4 Simple moving average 20 period

I see a buy signal and up to 3 orders are running
But when the price is below MA20 it does not automatically close the order
Help me to deal with

```
void OnTick()
  {
   double sma20 = iMA(Symbol(),PERIOD_H1,20,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,0);
   if(OrdersTotal()<3)
     {
      if(Low[1]>sma20)
        {
         bool ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,0.01,Ask,3,0,0,NULL,0,0,clrAliceBlue);
        }
     }

   for(int i=0; i<= OrdersTotal(); i++)
     {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS))
        {
         if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)
           {
            if(Close[1] < sma20)
              {
               bool ticket_close = OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),Ask,3,clrAliceBlue);
              }
           }

        }
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To close order with type `OP_BUY`, you should use `Bid` price insted of `Ask`.

Check why order isn't close by `GetLastError()`, in your case it should looks like:

```
bool ticket_close = OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),Bid,3,clrAliceBlue);
if(!ticket_close){
    Print("Error closing the order id: ", OrderTicket(), ", Error code: ", GetLastError()); 
}
```

Comment: +1 for the reference to GetLastError().  @tomgny, are you able to look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410403/istradeallowed-not-returning-what-i-would-expect ?